# Using SQL databases I need to gather data for a client from multiple sources

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have multiple databases that contain pieces of data that I need to collect on my clients.  Without giving any specific examples, due to confidentiality of the actual data, I will simply refer to what the field names are.

My Master table and three other tables contain the following columns -

```
Social Security Number, 
Medicare Number, 
Medicaid Number, 
Phone Number, 
Date of Birth, 
Last Name, 
First Name
```

The goal is to read a master record and, if all of the specified fields do not contain data, go and look at the other data sources to see if one of them DO contain the missing data.

Let me tell you an example of what the problem might be and see what suggestions you can give me to help me achieve my goal.  In my example I will call the master table Table 1.

`Table 1` - Is missing the DOB, SSN & Medicaid# for this record.
`Table 2` - Contains the DOB, Medicare# and Last & First Name.
`Table 3` - Has DOB, Medicaid#, Phone Number and Last & First Name.
`Table 4` - DOB, SSN, Medicare#, and Phone Number, and Last & First Name.

Currently, I am doing the following:

I created a view called `View 1` to combine all of the tables together. The uncommon fields are simply `NULL` for the tables no containing the field.

I have nested `case` statements for each of the desired fields.  I look to see if the field in `Table 1` is `NULL`, I begin doing a SubSelect statement to look for a matching record in the View 1 for each of the possible matching fields along with any secondary field to double check when needed - like if I do just DOB and Last & First Name matches.

I have a temporary table that gets updated with the findings prior to me running through the checks again.  I run through it multiple times since the first time through it might not have had a hit with one field, but the second time through it would find a match.

Does anyone see a better way of doing it thn what I have described?

Comment: Can you create the sample tables with fake sample rows so that we can get things done faster ?

Comment: I agree with Borat. It'll be way easier to suggest improvements if you give a concrete example schema and show what you are trying now. Complete generic object name sin the sample are appropriate. Use the simplest example you possible create while still demonstrating the necessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

This is the part that loses me:

> I have a temporary table that gets updated with the findings prior to
>   me running through the checks again. I run through it multiple times
>   since the first time through it might not have had a hit with one
>   field, but the second time through it would find a match.

Without that I would suggest left joining the tables to the master then using COALESCE() to find your best NOT NULL value.

```
COALESCE(Table_1.DOB,Table_2.DOB,Table_3.DOB,Table_4.DOB)
```

Comment: I'll take a look at the COALESCE.

Comment: By temporary table I am only using it to fill-in any missing data that I find for the record so that the next time I look for any additional missing data, in that record, I will have more data to get a possible match with.  Since I am back at work - where I can get the code - I'll paste in next just so you see in more detail what I am doing.

Comment: Too long to place here.  Sorry.  I'll take a look at COALESCE and let you know how it does.